# Can we use wcf WsDualHttpBinding(DUPLEX comm) for communicating between two different websites in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, duplex, wsdualhttpbinding

I want to make `duplex communication`(**CHAT like application**) between two different websites in asp.net.
I have seen lot of demos of duplex communication with two windows application (nettcpbinding) binding.

But I want to achieve this with two websites. Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference, just as you create a winforms app that has a reference to a WCF service, you can add a reference to your WCF service from your ASP.NET project as well.

However, if you want to make a chat like application (generally, any real-time communication with your web users), I recommend taking a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/%E2%80%8E).

*Update:*
If you're insisting on using WCF for implementing this, take a look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265695/ASP-Net-chatting-using-WCF-Services-and-JSon) which explains exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: can't the chat application be implemented through wcf wsdualhttpbinding?

Comment: What is your architecture? Where does your wcf service stand?

Comment: Planning to create wcf service stands between two different websites. It would have a call back class for both clients and the service after getting invoked from first client would call the callback method of second client...isn't it possible.. I mean I am still in process to create it..:)

Comment: You still need some way to call your service methods (Or trigger to call them) with javascript/ajax. See my updated answer with link to CodeProject article.